# Programmatically extract the .dlls from clickonce application .deploy files

Tags: c#, .net, dll, clickonce

I have a click once application which is deployed on server (network share), is there a way programmatically that extract the .dlls from the .dll.deploy files. Once we launch the application, it converts into dlls and places in user/appdata/local/... folder, but I need a way to extract the dlls without launching the application.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Simply rename the files by omitting the .deploy suffix and you're done.

Since this task could get a little tedious - depending on the number of files in your ClickOnce package - you might want to use a file renaming tool.

**Update**:
I just noticed that you were asking for a way to do this programmatically. That makes it even easier since you don't have to worry about finding a file renaming tool:

```
public class Program
{
    private const string SourcePath = "\\\\ClickOnceDeployDir";

    private const string TargetPath = "C:\\Users\\UserName\\Documents\\ClickOnceTargetDir";

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var sourceDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(SourcePath);
        var targetDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(TargetPath);
        // you can omit this step if you would like to do the renaming in-place
        Copy(sourceDirectory, targetDirectory);

        foreach (var file in targetDirectory.GetFiles("*.deploy", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            var directoryName = file.DirectoryName;
            if (directoryName != null)
            {
                // here it is: rename the file
                file.MoveTo(Path.Combine(directoryName, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name)));
            }
        }
    }

    private static void Copy(DirectoryInfo sourceDirectory, DirectoryInfo targetDirectory)
    {
        foreach (var file in sourceDirectory.GetFiles())
        {
            file.CopyTo(Path.Combine(targetDirectory.FullName, file.Name));
        }

        foreach (var directory in sourceDirectory.GetDirectories())
        {
            Copy(directory, targetDirectory.CreateSubdirectory(directory.Name));
        }
    }
}
```